# pagination Laravel Json Format

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i have two laravel project one is the front end and the other API so in my api i am sending data like so (note m using raw query i do not want to change the query part)
 ***API***
     ***TestController.php***

```
  public function index()
    {
     $results = DB::table('test_table')->paginate(2);
        return  TestResource::collection($results);     
    }
```

***TestResources.php***

```
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,  // <------
            'test_col' => $this->test_col,  // <------
        ];
    }
```

so when i post man this this is what i get

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "test_col": "Test one"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "test_col": "Test three"
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http://api.mylink/api/test?page=1",
        "last": "http://api.mylink/api/test?page=8",
        "prev": null,
        "next": "http://api.mylink/api/test?page=2"
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 8,
        "path": "http://api.mylink/api/test",
        "per_page": 2,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 15
    }
}
```

now for my front end

***frontend*** - >
        **TestController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => env('API_PATH')]);
        $response = $client->get('test');
        $response =  $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $output = (GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response));
        //dd($output);
       return view('test.index')->with('outputs',$output);
    }
```

when i `dd($output);` i get

```
{#237 ▼
  +"data": array:2 [▼
    0 => {#232 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"test_col": "Test one"
    }
    1 => {#230 ▼
      +"id": 3
      +"test_col": "Test three"
    }
  ]
  +"links": {#235 ▼
    +"first": "http://api.mylink/api/test?page=1"
    +"last": "http://api.mylink/api/test?page=8"
    +"prev": null
    +"next": "http://api.mylink/api/test?page=2"
  }
  +"meta": {#221 ▼
    +"current_page": 1
    +"from": 1
    +"last_page": 8
    +"path": "http://api.changemaker/api/test"
    +"per_page": 2
    +"to": 2
    +"total": 15
  }
}
```

any ways in my **index page** i am doing this

```
        @foreach($outputs->data as $output)              
           <h3> {{$output->test_col}}</h3>          
        @endforeach
 {{--{{$outputs->links()}}--}}
```

which works fine but when i comment out the `{{$outputs->links()}}`
then it gives an error

> Call to undefined method stdClass::links() (View:  ..

Comment: why don't you use `vue.js` for `api based` web application

Comment: Since you've decoded `$results` in your API `TestController` the `links()` method isn't available anymore. You've already seen the result of the request and that's what you have.

Comment: i think that in your controller ```output``` and in the view ```outputs``` may also cause the error